# Angular2 *ngIf with a value from Object inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

Id like to use a *ngIf inside a *ngFor where my role value is defined for that element.

My Template looks like that:

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let entry of naviEntries">
      <button *ngIf="{{entry.role}}" ...>{{entry.name}}</button>
</li>
```

And inside my Component:

```
enter code here`export class NaviComponent implements OnInit {
    naviEntries: NaviEntry[];
    visitor: boolean = true;
    user: boolean = false;
    admin: boolean = false;

    constructor() { ... }

    ngOnInit() {
        ...
        this.naviEntries.push({name: 'Home', link: '', role: 'visitor'});
        this.naviEntries.push({name: 'User', link: '/user', role: 'user'});
        this.naviEntries.push({name: 'Admin', link: '/admin', role: 'admin'});
        ...
```

Inside the ngOnInit function im checking for if User is logged in or user is an admin.

Now i'd like to check with *ngIf if the Object i pushed to NaviEntries is allowed to show at the Navi

Can i use an Object Value as an Variable used in my Component??

Excample:

NaviEntry => `{name: 'Admin', link: '/admin', role: 'admin'}`

In my Component => admin: boolean = true;

Template:

`*ngIf="{{entry.role}}"` => *ngIf="admin" => true => show item

Comment: you should use a proper interface for your user object, and enum for your user roles. You can do something like this: <button *ngIf="entry.role === userRoles[ADMIN]">{{entry.name}}</button>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like :

```
*ngIf="(entry.role === 'admin' && admin) || (entry.role === 'visitor' && visitor) || (entry.role === 'user' && user)"
```

Please read :

https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

As you are using it bit wrong way.

---

Optimised way to do :

```
// component side
roleAccess = {'admin' : false , 'user' : false , 'visitor' : true}

// template side
*ngIf="roleAccess[entry.role]"
```

Comment: i think you dont understand what i ment,
that would be fix but i have different roles: visitor, user, admin, ... and your way only would ask for admin

Comment: You can check each role same way , you havent define which role or how to define which is alowed to show or not , @xQp ,, let me know whats the condition I will make it llike

Comment: thats what i ment, you dont understand what i ment. - i have a Array of Objects with my NaviEntries. Each has its own role. And i want to check for that role individually, basicly, my question is if i can use an Object Value as an "Variable", for example my Entry has entry.role = 'admin', if this could be used as a check if this.admin=true/false;

Comment: Here you go @xQp

Comment: go where? i dont see an answer fitting to my question, sorry

Comment: Sorry forgot to update answer , please check now @xQp

Comment: ah now, yes that would lead to the right result, thank you, but is that the only way? in PHP its possible to use a Variable value as variablename. $a = 1; $b = 'a'; echo $$b; => 1, i hoped there is a way like that

Comment: @xQp, Please check updated answer, i think that is the best way of doing

Comment: Your ngIf should not have curly braces.